# Why is the div tag not changing CSS by its className?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a piece of React code:

```html
<div className="Tooltip-Wrapper" onMouseEnter={showTooltip} onMouseLeave={hideTooltip}>
  {children}
  {active && <div className="Tooltip-Tip">{text}</div>}
</div>
```

and have these classes in a scss file:

```css
.Tooltip-Wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.Tooltip-Tip {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 6px;
  color: var(--tooltip-text-color);
  background: var(--tooltip-background-color);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

but the divs do not have this styling on them. What could be the reason?

Comment: Going to need more context for this. Is it simply that none of the styles are being applied? Can you see them and the class in the browser's inspector? Are you getting any errors perhaps? Also, to make this easy just for the sake of checking, remove all the styles and put something very obvious. Such as `background-color: red;` and check if that is being applied.

Comment: what does Inspecting your browser tell you?